# How to solve VBoxManage not found issue

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I am using oracle virtual box 5.2.8 in windows 7 machine for using docker. Since I want to use docker swarm, I want to create few docker machines.

I tried to create docker machine with the following command:

```
sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox manager1
```

But I face the issue as:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error creating machine: Error with pre-create check: VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
```

In my machine C drive VBoxManage.exe file is present inside the path "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox".

When I executed the command **"which VBoxManage"**, it just comes to next line without any output or issue. Then executed **"type VBoxManage"** I face **"-bash: type: VBoxManage: not found".**

As I am new to docker and virtual box, I couldn't get a clue. Kindly provide inputs if I miss any points and how to proceed with docker-machine commands. Thanks!